# how to order the files with increasing order and later merge them

Tags: python, dat-protocol

I have a few files

results_0_**1**.dat
results_1_**1**.dat
results_17_**1**.dat
results_2_**1**.dat
results_22_**1**.dat
results_9_**1**.dat
results_11_**1**.dat
results_21_**1**.dat

I'd like to order them in increasing order 0,1,2...9,10,11....20,21,22.....the second number in this case 1 (in bold) it doesn't change because it's the name of the experiment. How could I do it?

I'd be grateful for any help :)

Comment: Please show the code you tried and that failed

Comment: i started with this code


import glob, os


os.chdir("C:/Users/adobi/PycharmProjects/start")
for file in glob.glob("resultados_*.dat"):
    print(file)

but it's showing only all  the dat files but not in order
I'm just starting with python so I'll be grateful for any suggestions

Comment: Is the answer below good enough? For more I'd need the code you used to produce the list and/or how you intend to use it after

Comment: ls -pv *.json| cut -f 1 -d '.' > /tmp/json_files.txt -- if you don't have program, you can do some manual steps to cut the first and the last part then arrange the files in spread sheet (excel).

Answer (score 0):

The [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function lets you manually define your sort criteria.

Since you want to sort by the `int` inbetween the `_`, we do just that.

`sorted(reslist, key=lambda element:int(element.split('_')[1]))`

Comment: sorted will return a list, so you can just iterate over that

Comment: I think i didn't understand that. I have files with numbers 1,16,17,2,3,11,23 and I'd like to get the order 1,2,3,11,16,17,23

Comment: that function will return the original names, sorted by their numbers